# Is that possible to link to different objects during compilation?

Tags: compilation, linker

Say I have two versions of a library which reside in folder "V1" and "V2", and I have two C files: "v1.c" and "v2.c", where "v1.c" will use library "V1", and "v2.c" will use library "V2". Note that "V1" and "V2" has the same interface. I tried:

```
g++ -c v1.c -o v1.o -I${V1}include
g++ -c v2.c -o v2.o -I${V2}include
g++ main.c -L${V1}lib v1.o -L${V2}lib v2.o -lsomething
```

Note that I provided 2 library paths before the 2 object files in the last linking step. Apparently it will not do what I expected, but I showed as it just to make my intention clear. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will use the first found suitable symbol, i.e. if you have a function 'bar' in both libraries, and libraries have the same name, function 'bar' from file which comes first in search will be used.

You can either give different names to symbols in different libraries (which would still have the same name), either give libraries different names.

Although I'm still not sure that renaming symbols will help, since linker could just link against firstly-encountered library and then complain that it doesn't contain the other needed symbol. The most sure way is renaming libraries.

Please comment if something is unclear, I'll try to explain further.